# Why is $(A\rtimes_\alpha G)\cong (A\otimes K(L^2(G)))^{\alpha\otimes Ad\rho}$?

Tags: operator-algebras, crystallography

I found a very strange isomorphism that I did not know have to prove.

Let $G$ be a finite discrete group. Let $Ad\rho_g(T)=\rho_g T\rho_g^*$ for all $T\in K(L^2(G))$ with $g\in G$ then:
\begin{align*}
(A\rtimes_\alpha G)\cong(A\otimes K(L^2(G)))^{\alpha\otimes Ad\rho}
\end{align*}
For which $A\otimes K(L^2(G))^{\alpha\otimes Ad\rho}$ is the fixed point algebra:
\begin{align*}
A\otimes K(L^2(G))^{\alpha\otimes Ad\rho}=\{a\otimes h\ |\ \alpha(a)\otimes Ad\rho_g(h)=a\otimes h\text{ for all }g\in G\}
\end{align*}
I do not know how to show this. Can anyone help? I found it [Yang] page 18.

[Yang]: Yang, Mingze. "[Crossed products by finite groups acting on low dimensional complexes and applications.](https://harvest.usask.ca/handle/10388/etd-10212004-000606)" PhD diss., University of Saskatchewan, 1997.

Comment: Is the groups $G$ finite? Otherwise i do not see why you would end up in the compacts.

Comment: In any case, if you want to show the result above for the finite case, just use the fact that the cross product is constructed via a concrete representation on $A \otimes B(L^2(G))$ in which each $a \cdot u_g$ is sent to a "generalized diagonal" and check that the invariant elements of the action $\alpha \otimes \mathrm{Ad} \rho$ are those same "generalized diagonals".

Comment: Yes, after checking the reference, the group is indeed finite.